# Is my understanding of "class" and "object" correct?

Tags: objective-c

I have started learning Objective-C, and I just wanted to verify that my understanding of the concepts "class" and "object" is correct. If this is the wrong forum, for these kind of über basic questions, please inform where I should be heading!

Anyway, I am studying Objective-C from a book on the subject, and I am now trying to making the knowledge "my own".

So far I have understood that "Class" refers to a description of the “objects” that can be “constructed” from this “Class”??? And that an “object” based on this “class” is understood by the specific “attributes” that this “object” can have and the specific “methods” this object can perform??? So “attributes” to me is similar to the physical description of the “object” and “methods” are the “actions” that this object can perform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class basically describes the attributes and methods you can base an object on.

Your understanding seems to be correct but you described a little confusing.
Let me give you a quick example:

Think about a cat. This shall be your class.
It has the following attributes:
-Name
-Colour
-Gender
-...

And some methods:
-Scratch
-Walk
-Meow
-...

Now you know what a cat is and what it can do.
With this knowledge you can create objects based on your class, for example:

A cat object named "garfield" (an instance of the class "cat") with the attributes:
Name: Garfield
Colour: Orange
Gender: Male
...
Which can scratch, walk, meow and... with it's methods.

I hope that was quite understandable.

Greetz :)

Comment: Oh noes... There the old and worn object-oriented analogies again... Please read http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/your-code-oop-or-poo.html and think again.

Comment: I didn't want to describe what or when to objectize but the difference between an object and a class...

Comment: I've been harsh. But in programming I don't have meowing cats in the system. The animal or cars analogies are a bit old, and I have seen them leading beginners astray, because where's the cat? Use real-world examples. An example is a User class representing people in a web application. A user object represents a real user logged in to the application; and the User class describes what a user can do: login, logout, change the email address, and so on. Beginners seem to grok this better than cats or cars.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking or cars etc is a great way to visualise object-orientated concepts.

You can have a class 'Vehicle' which has subclasses 'Boat', 'Plane', 'Motor vehicle', 'Bike' etc.

The 'Vehicle' class has methods (things you can tell it to do) 'Move', 'Stop', 'Turn' and attibutes 'Colour', 'Speed', 'Weight' etc. All the subclasses have the same methods and attibutes, as they 'inherit' them from the superclass.

Whilst they all move, they might do it differently (fly, float, roll, drive etc), by 'overriding' their superclass' 'move' method.

The actual car that you drive is an 'Instance' of the 'car' class. Your wife's car is another instance of the car class. Each instance has it's own attributes (colour etc).

Comment: Easy to understand explanation without the fuss.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 'class' refers to the type, and 'object' refers to an instance of a class.

So you may have a class Bike which describes a bike, and 3 objects bike1, bike2 and bike3 which are each instances of the class Bike.

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: @DAWO: Please remember to upvote the answers that helped you and select one that you mark as the "accepted answer".

Comment: All of these answers did help me a lot to really get my "own" understanding in place. As this is my first "question", it seems that I cannot "upvote" any of your answers. And it is difficult in this case just to pick out ONE answer to be the best, or most correct! It is really the iteration of the same explanation but with a slight difference that helped me learn! So cars, Chuck Norris, cats and bikes were really benificial!

Comment: I guess that picking one answer you liked best will not leave the others in tears here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Think of `class` as a blueprint for objects. An object is also called "instance" - an actual "working copy" of a class.

An attribute is actually what you'd expect - in some languages it is also called a "property". Something like a color for example or a location, something that can be set and/or retrieved. Basically, from the developer's point of view, an attribute is mostly a variable that is bound to the object in that it is not a "global variable".

A "method" is like a function you can call on an object to do something.

For example, take a class named `Address`. It would have attributes like `Street` or `ZIP` or `Country`. Also, it could have a method `GetDistance` to calculate the distance from your current location to the address. Then you could create any number of objects: my address, your address, Chuck Norris's address, etc.

*PS: Do I get a +1 for the Chuck Norris reference...? :-)*